Adding more (3rd) criteria to COUNTIFS
i'm creating a log to record replaced ropes at a climbing gym, with various "averages" output for overview.
i'd like to add an option to filter these "averages" by rope type, selected in a drop-down.
i already have the "averages" displayed using COUNTIFS with two criteria, and it works perfectly.
but when i add this drop-down match criteria (3rd criteria using COUNTIF), i can't seem to make the formula work.  adding this 3rd criteria gives faulty output (currently "0", when it should display "1")
i highlighted pertinent cells in turquois.  hoping for a simple solution/explanation.
attached file.
i tried adding 3rd criteria to COUNTIFS but it doesn't work.

can you explain in words what do you count?

provide what is the current version of the cell formula and the version when you tried 3rd condition. It may be a simple syntax error.

highlighted in turquois (cell K4, under "core"), i'm counting all logged fields with check marks on "core", AND rope type that matches F2.  i only added rope type to the first date log, but rope type field will be added to all dates.  once this formula works, it will be applied to "sheet", "fat", etc.

formula that currently works: =COUNTIFS($R$4:4,"TRUE",$R$3:$3,$K$3).  formula that i'm trying to get to work:  =COUNTIFS($R$4:4,"TRUE",$R$3:$3,$K$3, $R$4:$4,$F$2)

BTW- if i keep the 3rd criteria only, it functions and counts properly: =COUNTIFS($R$4:$4,$F$2)

try:
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(R4:4, TRUE, R3:3&OFFSET(R4:4,,5), K3&F2))


for L4 it will be:
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(R4:4, TRUE, R3:3&OFFSET(R4:4,,4), L3&F2))

for M4 - OFFSET(range,,3) etc.
or if you want to drag it K4:
=INDEX(COUNTIFS($R4:4, TRUE, $R3:3&OFFSET($R4:4,,6-COLUMN(A1)), K3&$F2))


but instead of per-cell formula its better to use arrays. use this in K4 after you delete everything in L4:O4 range:
=INDEX(MAP(K3:O3, {5,4,3,2,1}, LAMBDA(x, y, 
 COUNTIFS($R4:4, TRUE, $R3:3&OFFSET($R4:4,,y), x&$F2))))



this worked on "core" (K4), but not on the rest of cells (L4:O4)

@ChulhoChang answer updated with array variant

so apparently i'm not understanding how the solution formula works because i can't seem to make similar formula for another cell/range.  would you guys mind having a look at cell D4?  it's suppose to count two conditions: 1) "R"s in given row in sheet:DATA, 2) rope type column in sheet:DATA matches F2

@ChulhoChang you are basically joining (fusing) 2nd and 3rd criterion to simulate AND logic because your 3rd criterion is very unluckily placed. if you would have non-open ranges it would be easier to visually grasp as this would be written as S3:AA3 & X4:AF4 where both ranges needs to be of equal size to avoid array errors. but you are using open ranges R3:3 so joining it with X4:4 would not do coz 2nd range would be smaller column wise. so we use OFFSET to offset the 2nd range by 5 columns to the right. then the value 5 is actually an offset distance between S3 and X4

i'm starting to understand.  but why the "index"?  i thought index needed range, col, row?

@ChulhoChang you can exchange INDEX for ARRAYFORMULA. af is needed to process array of joint (&) set. INDEX is just shorter to type. both of them are processing arrays in a same way
